# How to create a programming language with other

Tags: java, programming-languages, translate

### How to create a programming language with other

I Want to Create a Programming language that can translate to java code and compile with javac ??

for example

```
 var x=2;
 if x== 2 then x=5;
```

---

**please help**

Comment: Why would you want to translate to Java code? You can write a compiler for your language that targets the JVM without doing that. In any event, how to make a programming language is **way** beyond the scope of an SO question.

Comment: If you just want to parse and execute user input, then you can do this with something like a [recursive descent parser](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/318667/Mathematical-Expression-Parser-Using-Recursive-Des) - no need to implement a full blown programming language.

Comment: Read The Dragon Book and learn ANTLR: http://www.antlr.org

Comment: Google for "Java DSL".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This task is reasonable, but requires education. You can start with [how to make compiler](https://www.google.ru/search?q=how%20to%20make%20compiler) and [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/).